# do i need to install react-tap-event-plugin to make the date picker to work in the browser?

Tags: reactjs, material-design, redux, react-redux, material-ui

So I have an issue running this code...in my browser. it gives no exception..

```
import React from 'react'
import DatePicker from 'material-ui/DatePicker';

const Datetime = () => {
return (
    <div> 
        <DatePicker hintText="start datetime" />
    </div>
    )
}

export default Datetime;
```

it does not seem like it's firing an event handler when i click on it. So i need to call injectTapEventPlugin() to make the material ui event to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
injectTapEventPlugin();
import DatePicker from 'material-ui/DatePicker';
```

Comment: lol..they should rename the library to something else..it is kinda confusing to have it called..react-tap-event